# How do I demote/promote selected subtrees?

Tags: org-mode

(current as of org 8.2.10)

I have a thing ([shameless plug](https://github.com/talexand/gitscroll)) that outputs a simple snippet of org-headings in a single file that look like this:

```
* little boys
  - snakes
  - snails
  - puppy dog tails
* little girls
  - sugar
  - spice
  - everything nice
** addendum
  - etc.
```

These are meant to go into another file through `org-insert` functions, specifically, a subheading of that other file.

In order to do that I have to demote all of the headings so that they slide nicely into place. How can I do that?

I tried:

- `C-x r t` to prepend asterisks; this adds asterisks to every line
- `C-x h M-S-<right>` to try demoting the whole selection; this only demoted the first line

#### Further issue: org-metaright does not demote subtrees

Commenters were correct that `C-x h M-<right>` (`org-metaright`) promotes or demotes visible selections. However, this ignores their subtrees, resulting in reordering of their substructure. The same behavior occurs with `org-do-demote` called on a selection.

Comment: What command does `M-S-<right>` run? For me (Emacs 24.3.1, Org 8.2.10), `M-<right>` runs `org-metaright`, and that does the proper behavior (that is, adds a single asterisk to the "little boys" and "little girls" lines). Similarly, `C-x h M-x org-do-demote` also works properly.

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, but doesn't `org-metaright` operate on a selected region?

Comment: Demoting and promoting works with selected regions, if that might be of use in this situation.

Comment: I cannot find `org-insert-file` as a standard orgmode command.

Comment: Thanks for the good comments. I updated the question after trying those functions explicitly.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Can't you just call `show-all` before `org-do-demote`?

Comment: @Malabarba That would work, but it would create a messy display or ask a lot from the display buffer with files that are megabytes in size. It's also unintuitive, interface-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Org headlines are simply lines starting with a `*`. So you can cycle
through all of them and manually insert an `*` on each one to get the
effect you want.

```el
(defun endless/demote-everything (number beg end)
  "Add a NUMBER of * to all headlines between BEG and END.
Interactively, NUMBER is the prefix argument and BEG and END are
the region boundaries."
  (interactive "p\nr")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (save-match-data
        (widen)
        (narrow-to-region beg end)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (let ((string (make-string number ?*)))
          (while (search-forward-regexp "^\\*" nil t)
            (insert string)))))))
```

At first you might be worried this would catch undesired edge cases, such as a `#+SRC_BLOCK` where one of the lines starts with a `*`. But `org-mode` itself uses this method to identify headlines, so no org buffer should ever contain a `*` as the first char of a line unless it's a headline.

Comment: I think it is more usual for functions to act on the (possibly narrowed) buffer when there is no region. Also  why use of save-match-data in this specific function ? Most other functions/commands do not preserve the match data anyway.
Lastly, in fact org uses "^\\*+ " (aka org-outline-regexp-bol), i.e. there must be a space after the stars.

Comment: It's not necessary to _manually_ search for the org-mode headlines. There is an API for this and you can use the function `org-map-tree` like in this example from the Emacs wiki: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#orgheadline9

Answer (score 6):

If I understand it correctly, you have a list of subtrees

```
* A
** A1
*** A1a
* B
** B1
```

and want to insert them into another subtree

```
* First
** First Sub
* Second
```

at the right level:

```
* First
** First Sub
*** A
**** A1
***** A1a
*** B
**** B1
* Second
```

As this is Emacs (and org-mode of course), there is a function for this ;-)

Just use `org-paste-subtree` like so:

1. save your new list in the kill ring (select and <kbd>M-w</kbd>)
2. enter `***` after *First Sub*
3. call `org-paste-subtree`

The function is described as

> Paste the clipboard as a subtree, with modification of headline level.

and will work for demoting **and** promoting the subtree in the kill ring.

org-mode can even be configured to use this style of yank every time a subtree is yanked into a subtree.  Customize the variable `org-yank-adjusted-subtrees` and you can use <kbd>C-y</kbd> instead of `org-paste-subtree` in the example above.

For me this was especially useful when I wanted to promote all subtrees under one toplevel.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you described can also be solved with the functions `outline-promote` and `outline-demote`.

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback. Just adding to my answer, I've discovered that
there also exist functions `org-promote-subtree` and `org-demote-subtree`.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not the subtrees are visible, if you

- position the cursor at the beginning of the first headline,
- you are running with `Transient-Mark` mode enabled (the default),
- mark the whole thing as your region so that it is highlighted,
- do <kbd>M-right</kbd>,

all of the headlines (and their subtrees) should be demoted one level. If that is not how your setup is working, something is broken: you should investigate the situation and fix it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue as the OP, and posted an up to date question with an MCVE at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/56155/15483 in hopes to find a fix.

Comment: @bgoodr:  Try `M-right` and `M-left` instead of `M-S-right` and `M-S-left`. I think I got that wrong above.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix that. Sorry for the confusion I caused and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you too. I've marked your answer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/56155/15483 and updated that question accordingly with **Update 1** to indicate my opinions on the defect here.

Answer (score 0):

Latest release (develop branch) of [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) has the functions `org-promote-subtree` and `org-demote-subtree` that works perfectly. They can be triggered via `, s h` and `, s l`, respectively, by keeping cursor on the root of the sub-tree.

I also find it convenient to select region in org file and promote/demote outlines within scope of selection. This can be done by using `org-do-promote` and `org-do-demote` functions.